# How do I remove text from a node?

Tags: javascript, dom

```
<div id="blah">
    <img src="yadda.svg" />
    <span>
        Text of great importance
    </span>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</div>
```

Now I know I can easily clear `#blah` from **all** content:

```
for (let node of Array.from(document.getElementById('blah').childNodes))) node.remove()
```

But I only want to get rid of all text (in this case `Lorem ipsum...`) I do not want to get rid of the image nor of the span nor of the text of the span.

`Lorem` was likely inserted into this `div` via `document.getElementById('blah').appendChild(document.createTextNode('Lorem...'))`

Comment: iterate over its direct children and check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType ?

Comment: It's unfortunate that text nodes can't be targeted using CSS selectors.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`nextsibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling) to target the text node and remove it.

```js
document.querySelector('#blah > span').nextSibling.remove()
```

```html
<div id="blah">
    <img src="yadda.svg" />
    <span>
        Text of great importance
    </span>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is super brittle and I don't honestly recommend it, but if your html is exactly that format always then this does work.

```js
const wrapper = document.querySelector('#blah');

const stripped = Array.from(wrapper.children).reduce((a, c) => a + c.outerHTML, '');

wrapper.innerHTML = stripped;
```

```html
<div id="blah">
    <img src="yadda.svg" />
    <span>
        Text of great importance
    </span>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</div>
```